# What is meant by $\mathbb R^m$ in this context?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying some introductory Linear Algebra text. So far, it's explained $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$, $\mathbb R^n$ — all understood. Then $\mathbb R^m$ came out of the blue with no background provided. Further Googling only confused me more as the available content turned out to be too advanced for a beginner to the topic.

Here are two bits from the text that I'm reading:

> If ***A*** is an *m* $\cdot$ *n* matrix with columns $\mathbf a_1$, $\ldots$, $\mathbf a_n$, and if $\mathbf b$ is in $\mathbb R^m$, the matrix equation ***A***$\mathbf x$ = $\mathbf b$ has the same solution set as the vector equation $x_1\mathbf a_1 + \cdots + x_n\mathbf a_n$, which, in turn, has the same solution set as the system of linear equations whose augmented matrix is $[\mathbf a_1 \cdots \mathbf a_n \mathbf b]$.

And

> Let ***A*** be an *m* $\cdot$ *n* matrix. Then the following statements are logically equivalent:
>
> - For each $\mathbf b$ in $\mathbb R^m$, the equation ***A***$\mathbf    x$ = $\mathbf b$ has a solution.
> - Each $\mathbf b$ in $\mathbb R^m$ is a linear combination of the    columns of ***A***.
> - The columns of ***A*** span $\mathbb R^m$.

In the second bit, I understand what a linear combination is (bulletpoint 2) and the concept of span (bulletpoint 3). But without an explanation of $\mathbb R^m$, I'm unable to get the complete picture.

Question: What is $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers. How many real numbers are in the vector.

Comment: $m$ is just an arbitrary natural number. You know what $\mathbb{R}^n$ is: it is the set (or vector space) of all n-tuples with real entries. $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the exact same thing except instead of letting $n$ represent an arbitrary natural number, they let $m$ be an arbitrary natural number. It is the set (or vector space, in this context) of all m-tuples with real entries.

Comment: It's puzzling to me that this question would get as many downvote as it did.

Comment: Ah. $\mathbb R^m$ in regards to matrices now comes up in Chapter 2 of the text that I'm reading. But I was on Chapter 1. So I understand the downvotes — they assumed I should already be familiar with the notation when I wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a concise answer that addresses what I think is the main point of confusion:

When looking at a matrix $A$, we usually say that the matrix is $m\times n$. That is, $m$ is generally a placeholder for the number of rows in $A$ and $n$ for the number of columns.

Now, suppose we've chosen such a matrix. If $x$ is a (column-) vector, then $Ax$ only makes sense (by the rules of matrix multiplication) if $x$ is in $\Bbb R^n$ (that is, the number of entries in $x$ is the number of columns in $A$). On the other hand, the result $Ax$ must be an element of $\Bbb R^m$ for that same reason (the number of entries in $Ax$ is the number of rows in $A$).

With all that said, the equation $Ax=b$ can only make sense if $x$ is in $\Bbb R^n$ and $b$ is in $\Bbb R^m$.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of linear algebra, $\mathbb R$ signifies the set of real numbers. When used with superscript which is not a number, it signifies the set of vectors (with real number as elements) with the superscript as the amount of elements. meaning: $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of vectors with $n$ elements, each from the real numbers set.

Since $n$ is just a parameter - we can use different letters for it (for example - if $n$ is already in use for a different purpose in the question).

In conclusion: $\mathbb R^m$ is the group of real number vectors with $m$ elements.

PS. this was not in the question, but $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ is the set of matrices with $n\times m$ elements, each belong to the real numbers. $n$ is the number of rows, $m$ is the number of columns.

Comment: ${\mathbb R}^n$ is a set and not a group. Other than that good explanation

Comment: @mathreadler I'm gonna go out on a limb and say $\mathbb R^n$ can be reasonably taken as a real vector space, which makes it an (additive) group among other things.  But true, 'group' is being used very haphazardly in this answer.

Comment: Yes technically you are right, but at this early point in learning mixing up concepts and words likely create confusion for the student which would hinder learning.

Comment: I'd say the bigger mistake here is to say $R^{n\times m}$ is "the group of matrices," since groups of matrices usually consist of just invertible matrices and the operation is multiplication.

Comment: So the $m$ in $\mathbb R^m$ is in no way related to the $m$ in the $m$ $\cdot$ $n$ matrix?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, English is not my native language - thus my limited terminology.. @Duos - it **is** related. the vector from $\mathbb R^m$ has the same number of elements as the rows of the matrices from $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. this is required so that vector-matrix multiplication is defined. see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: Yes a matrix $M$ in the set $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ takes a column vector $v$ from the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ if you do the matrix product $Mv$.

Comment: Ah, I now realize my question wasn't so clear. My mistake. But I've received the answer I was looking for — it's the one I've now accepted. Thanks for your help and your time, anyway. Much appreciated.